# Terminology regarding different built-in array methods Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, terminology

When using the built-in methods available for arrays in Javascript, some methods will act directly on the calling array.
For example, myArray.sort(), will sort myArray in ascending order, alphabetically or numerically.

```
myArray.sort();
// sort() acts directly on myArray, changing it in its place thereafter
// ... also myArray.reverse() amongst others.
```

While other methods such as slice(), require there be something, either a variable or other output for it to return its value to...

```
var need_a_new_array = myArray.slice(10, 21);
// a new placeholder is needed for the results of slice... if not using 
// the results immediately (i.e. passing to another function or 
// outputting the results)
```

I was wondering what is the proper terminology for these methods and their differences. I am using arrays as an example here, but I'm sure that the
same probably holds true for objects in general.
I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't on SO, but answers your question: [What is the term used to describe a function/method that modifies the object it's called on?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343756/what-is-the-term-used-to-describe-a-function-method-that-modifies-the-object-it)

Answer (score 2):

The correct terms are *mutator* and *accessor*.

A [mutator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) *mutates* (changes) the object it is called on, while an accessor *accesses* (and returns) the value of the object it is called on.

You can see examples of the two types by looking at the method listing for [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods). Note that they are divided into categories, two of which are [Mutator methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods) (*"These methods modify the array"*) and [Accessor methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Accessor_methods) (*"These methods do not modify the array and return some representation of the array."*)

Mutators can not be called on [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

See also this related question on the software engineering SE: [What is the term used to describe a function/method that modifies the object it's called on?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343756/what-is-the-term-used-to-describe-a-function-method-that-modifies-the-object-it)

Comment: Thanks Herohtar! Straight from MDN. Can't argue with that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The terms you're looking for are 'immutable' and 'mutable' . `Array.prototype.sort` is a mutable method in that it 'mutates' (changes) the original array, where as `Array.prototype.slice` is immutable as it creates a new array with the result and leaves the original array intact.

Comment: whoa thanks for such as super-fast and concise answer!

Comment: This isn't correct. "mutable" and "immutable" are terms referring to *objects* -- things that can be changed vs can't be.

Comment: Almost. The correct term is `mutating` vs `non-mutating`